# How to insert javascript variable in HTML div

Tags: javascript

I have this

```
<div id="chart1" class="bar-chart secondary" data-total="42" animated>
<span class="bar-chart--inner" style="width:42%;"></span>
<span class="bar-chart--text">42% </span>
</div>
```

and I have one javascript variable `var score` that I need to assign to `data-total="42"`and <span `class="bar-chart--text">42% </span>`
My intention is to replace 42 with my javascript variable. I have tried this
`document.getElementById("chart1").innerHTML =score` that I have found from this forum but did not work. Please help.

```
<div id="chart1" class="bar-chart secondary" data-total="document.getElementById("chart1").innerHTML =score" animated>
    <span class="bar-chart--inner" style="width:42%;"></span>
    <span class="bar-chart--text">42% </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're setting a data attribute to a string; you'll want to put the JS somewhere where it'll actually execute, like in a script tag or event handler or something.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.bar-chart--text').innerText = "52%"`

Comment: @TJBlackman I have just tried it but didn't work. I guess I'm messing up where to place the <script> tags. My tags are in the header section. NB: I have very basic skills in Javascript

Comment: Put your JS Code to the end. Above the closing body tag.

Comment: Yes, the element does not exist yet if you put the script in the head.

Comment: Also you cannot nest quotes

Comment: If you wrap in a load handler, you can keep the script in the head: `window.addEventListener('load',function() { document.querySelector('.bar-chart--text').innerText = "52%" })`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

get the element in a JS script

then set elem.dataset.total

```js
document.getElementById("chart1").dataset.total = score
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="chart1" class="bar-chart secondary" data-total="42" animated>
    <span class="bar-chart--inner" style="width:42%;"></span>
    <span class="bar-chart--text">42% </span>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var score = 20

    document.getElementById("chart1").dataset.total = score
  </script>
</body>
```

For setting the html of an element, you can use innerHTML, just need to select that element in another lookup.

```js
document.querySelector(".bar-chart--text").innerHTML = score
```

Comment: This worked, Thank you!